# How to get the current date without time in scala

Tags: scala, date, datetime, calendar

I want to get the current date so I used:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

But as it `.getTime()` it is returning:

```
Fri Jul 11 15:07:03 IST 2014
```

I want only date in any format but without the time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You may use formatting:

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-y")
println(format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))
```

Answer (score 81):

```
scala> java.time.LocalDate.now
res4: java.time.LocalDate = 2014-07-11
```

Comment: `error: object time is not a member of package java`

Comment: Use Java 8 or higher.

Comment: ^ Java 8+ might not be an option for everybody.  This answer should have been qualified with that requirement.

Answer (score 20):

Since Java 8, you can also use `LocalDate` class:

```
println(java.time.LocalDate.now)
```

OR

```
java.time.LocalDate.now.toString
```

Comment: Thanks!! `scala> java.time.LocalDate.now.toString /n  res2: String = 2018-11-14`

Comment: @TonyFraser pls add it as another answer. I would like to upvote it

Answer (score 5):

You need to use SimpleDate formate method. You can specify which formate you want.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");    
String dateSelected = formatter.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 5):

```
val dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa")
var submittedDateConvert = new Date()
submittedAt = dateFormatter.format(submittedDateConvert)
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 5):

In case if you want to format the date in your way.

```
println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-YYYY").format(java.time.LocalDate.now))
```

Answer (score 1):

if someone needs the *date* in a format so that to be able to add to PostgreSQL here we go:

```
import java.util.Calendar
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance
val now = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime.getTime)
```

or in one line:

```
val now = new Timestamp(java.util.Calendar.getInstance.getTime.getTime)
```